# EC2 instance IAM role changes after patching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Some EC2 instances have custom IAM roles which allow them to access certain other services like SQS, ECS etc. Access policies for these services are added to custom IAM roles which have been attached to these EC2 instances. Sometimes after patching instances from SystemsManager, the EC2 IAM role changes to AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup. This causes processes to not work as they lose access to the SQS/ECS service.
How do we avoid this?

Comment: Create a new role, assign `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM` policy and other necessary permissions for the EC2 application to do its job to the role. then attach the role to the ec2

Comment: Thanks! I had the SSMManagedInstanceCore instead of AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policy attached. @ArunK

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: No I still see instances reverting to AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup from EC2 custom role. Even Ec2 compute environments created by ECS or other services are getting the wrong role @ArunK

Comment: Any help here @ArunK

Comment: Is it happening for every instance even if you create a new instance?

Comment: you should be able to get some help in this chat room. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat

Comment: Cant get into the room because of low reputation @ArunK

Comment: I didn't realize.